# java: Use Constructor of another class

Tags: java, constructor

I searched the Forum now for half an hour and i just dont find a solution..
I have to write a Programm "Student" that has 2 constructors (one with parameters). Now i am trying to test it in my testclass "StudentTest2" but i just cant get to the constructor of class Student.

My Class Student is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student{

  boolean validMatNumber;
  String name;
  private int matrikelnummer;
  //statisch, da sich die Anzahl der Studenten global ändern muss
  static int numberOfStudents;
  static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

  public Student() {
    new Student();
    students.add(this);
    numberOfStudents++;
  }

  public Student(String name, int matrikelnummer){
    if (matrikelnummer > 9999 && matrikelnummer < 100000){
      validMatNumber = true;
      this.matrikelnummer = matrikelnummer;
      this.name = name;
      students.add(this);
      numberOfStudents++;  
    }
    else{
      validMatNumber = false;
    }
  }

  String printInformation(){
    return ("Name: "+ this.name + " Matrikelnummer: " + this.matrikelnummer);
  }
  void printAllInformation(){
    for(Student aStudent: students){
      System.out.println("Name: " + aStudent.getName() + "Matrikelnummer: " +
                         aStudent.getMatrikelnummer());
    }
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getMatrikelnummer(){
    return matrikelnummer;
  }

  boolean isValidMatNumber(){
    //Da die Matrikelnummer 5 stellig sein soll und nicht mit 0 anfangen darf,
    //habe ich diesen Zahlenbreich gewählt
    if (matrikelnummer > 9999 && matrikelnummer < 100000){
      validMatNumber = true;
      return validMatNumber;
    }
    else{
      validMatNumber = false;
      return validMatNumber;
    }
  }


  static int getNumberOfStudents(){
    return numberOfStudents;
  }
```

And my testclass so far is (doesnt work tho):

```
public class StudentTest2{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Student s1 = new Student(Peter, 12345);
  }
}
```

i get the error

StudentTest2.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    Student s1 = new Student(Peter, 12345);
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Peter
  location: class StudentTest2

Comment: It is a perfectly normal error to get when you are using variables you have not declared anywhere (remember, typing `Peter` means you reference a variable, typing `"Peter"` gives you a string).

Comment: now thats embarassing... thanks!

Comment: Just a note but you can change your function `isValidMatNumber()` to one line : `return matrikelnummer > 9999 && matrikelnummer < 100000;`

As you are basically just returning the result of the condition.

Comment: @Schurke - not embarrassing. Simple mistake to make; it's all a learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor, you have defined a `String` and an `int`;

```
public Student(String name, int matrikelnummer){
```

And your problem is - you are trying to pass in `Peter, 12345`, but `Peter` is not a `String`. You just need to surround a `String` with `"`

For example:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Peter", 12345);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, my Problem is solved with that! (:

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a `String` and an `int`:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Peter", 12345);
```

or what do you think `Peter` is? it is absolutely unknown for the compiler. It results in the message "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: wow... im more than stupid. thanks for that!

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

The Student class constructor you are trying to use accepts a `String` and an `int` values as parameters.

So your code should be:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Peter", 12345);
```

Or you declare a variable call peter as indicated by the compiler:

```
String Peter = "Peter";
Student s1 = new Student(Peter, 12345);
```

Comment: im pretty new to java, thanks for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome @Schurke, vote up my answer if it helped.

Comment: i did.. but i have less then 15 reputation an therefore it isnt recogniced...

Comment: You don't need 15 reputation to vote up an answer. May be you instead voted down!

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your constructor:

```
    public Student() {
    new Student(); // infinite recursive calls, delete this line
    students.add(this);
    numberOfStudents++;
  }
```

then refer to `Peter`as a `String` or a variable containing a `String`.

Comment: my job was to write a constructor without parameters that takes the initialising work. how could i do it otherwise?

Comment: @Schurke you just wrote it, and inside it you call it again, which will call it again and again until you get the famous `StackOverflowError`

Comment: you are right. do you have a solution for my task?
"Create a constructor without parameters, that does the necessary initialization work of creating a new Student-Object"

Comment: when you wrote `public Student() {...}` that means you created a constructor without parameters, I disagree with the fact you declared a list of students inside the `Student` class, I think `StudentTest2`is made for something like that. check [here](https://codeshare.io/aljZZD)

Comment: alright i got it now, thanks! And thanks for the nice Website!

Comment: @Schurke enjoy coding :D